# Is there a way to change the text color of a textarea?

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to change the text color of my code? I tried `color: red;` but it just changes the background color. My code is here: https://replit.com/@Astro3000/jscompiler#index.html, and the site is here: https://jscompiler.astro3000.repl.co/

Comment: Colour of your code? Don't you think the colour of rendering text?

Comment: BTW the replit link doesn't work :(

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing it in the css without realizing that it wouldn't work. Thanks for your help! I think it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links don't seem to work but the code

html:

```
<form>
  <textarea> </textarea>
</form>
```

css:

```
textarea {
  color: red;
}
```

works fine in codepen.

edit: seems your site uses inline code

```
<form>
  <textarea style="color:red;"> </textarea>
</form>
```